# Android service not called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-manifest, android-permissions

This is my service:

```
public class KeepAliveService  extends Service {
Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
public void onCreate()
{
    Log.i("","KEEPALIVE onCreate");
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    alarm.setAlarm(this);
    Log.i("","KEEPALIVE onCreate start command");
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
{
    alarm.setAlarm(this);
    Log.i("","KEEPALIVE onStart");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    return null;
}
}
```

I have it declared like this in my manifest, after my :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:name="com.vidyo.vidyomod.VidyoModApplication"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    tools:replace="android:icon">
    <activity
        android:name="com.vidyo.vidyomod.activities.BaseActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="vidyocore" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name="com.vidyo.vidyomod.KeepAliveService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:process=":your_service" >
    </service>
    <receiver android:process=":remote" android:name="com.vidyo.vidyomod.utils.Alarm"></receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.vidyo.vidyomod.utils.AutoStart">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

And on my onCreate of my BaseActivity, I do this:

```
    Intent i= new Intent(BaseActivity.this, KeepAliveService.class);
    startService(i);
```

I debugged, my breakpoint at startService does stop, but OnCreate is not called. why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put your `Service` and your `BroadcastReceiver` inside your `application` tag:

```
<application>
<service
    android:name="com.vidyo.vidyomod.KeepAliveService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:process=":your_service" >
</service>
<receiver android:name="com.vidyo.vidyomod.utils.AutoStart">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>
```

Also, you are starting service in  a different process.

```
<service
    android:name="com.vidyo.vidyomod.KeepAliveService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:process=":your_service" >
```

The debugger is attached to your main process. When the new one starts, it has no debugger attached, so it will ignore your breakpoints.

Comment: Added it inside the application, but still when I debug the onCreate is not entered

Comment: try to remove the line  android:process=":your_service"